# MATLAB - Problems with large arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

The code below works great for small vectors.

```
[X1, X2]=meshgrid(Data1(:,1), Data2(:,1));
[Y1, Y2]=meshgrid(Data1(:,2), Data2(:,2));
[Z1, Z2]=meshgrid(Data1(:,3), Data2(:,3));

Rxy = sqrt( (X1-X2).^2 + (Y1-Y2).^2 );
Rz = abs( Z1-Z2 );

[I1, I2] =find( Rxy<=100 & Rz<=0.2);
```

However, as I work with a large amount of data, matlab does not support and does not work correctly. Matlab generates the following message:

> Error using repmat Requested 75027x68517 (38.3GB) array exceeds
>   maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this
>   limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to Become unresponsive.
>   See array size limit or preference panel for more information.

Seeking alternatives to "out of memory error," but I'm not getting an efficient manner. I made a loop to function is, but it was extremely slow.

Comment: Are you using a 64 bit system?

Comment: Yikes... that matrix size is HUGE.  Let's take a step back.  Can you explain to us what it is you're trying to do?  If we know the purpose of that code, then we may even be able to provide alternatives.

Comment: Yes, i'm using windows x64.

Comment: I'm an oceanographer and work with bathymetric data analysis (.xyz).
Where X is position, position and Y is Z is a water depth
I'm making a program to join the line segments that will make up a terrain profile. First, I select and identify the segments, posteriomente, I find the set of intersection between the two segments. Within this set I find the best connection point. This point should be less than 10m distance and difference Z (water depth) of less than 0.2m. So I find the possible points for joining the profiles.

Comment: My problem is only in discovering the junction points, since I buy all points within the set. If you use the code loop is very time consuming, using meshgrid the wheel very fast code, but has a size limit. I'm trying to solve this dilemma.

I think I explained properly.

Comment: If you have enough memory, MATLAB should not stop you from creating that array (Assuming you have >40 GB of RAM). See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91711-what-is-the-maximum-matrix-size-for-each-platform). It may be the limitation of `repmat`. Try to not use repmat to replicate arrays. See [here](http://www.vincentcheung.ca/research/matlabindexrepmat.html). Also, if you feel using loop is costing you time, why don't you write a MEX-file, which will save you time.

Comment: Parag, is very nice tip. I will study more about it. I try make with MEX-FIles, but i I didn't get it yet

Comment: How much RAM do you have? Matlab has a preference (under MATLAB / Workspace / MATLAB array size limit) that limits the possible size of an array. To what value is it set in your installation?

Comment: you must use a database in case of your array size and dynamically pull/push your data from database. using database in matlab is easy.

Comment: Hello everyone who tried to help me!
I did not get the solution, I study a little more or change language.

I take this post and ask someone two tips with more experience in the subject.

The first is: Any good material teaching the use MEX-Files or vectors comparison methods, which will not occur execessivo memory usage.

Another tip is: It would be valid to use the Fortran instead of Matlab?

I still believe that Matlab can handle these large arrays.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `meshgrid` is using `repmat` internally to create some massive matrices. Have a look at [bsxfun](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), allows these types of operations without actually replicating the data. From the help:

> C = bsxfun(fun,A,B) applies the element-by-element binary operation
>   specified by the function handle fun to arrays A and B, with singleton
>   expansion enabled.

So line 5 of your example would become (untested, don't have Matlab available right now:

```
Rxy = sqrt( bsxfun(@minus, Data1(:,1), Data2(:,1)).^2 + bsxfun(@minus, Data1(:,2), Data2(:,2)).^2 );
```

and change the line below analogously.